# How to remove ffmpeg implementation

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I have a code which uses the ffmpeg library and some of the APIs for the encode and decode functionalities.

Now I want remove the complete implementation of ffmpeg and make my project independent of ffmpeg. Is there anyways that I can achieve this and retain the functionality of the project ?

Comment: Probably you need to implement your own ffmpeg.

Comment: I though of it, but is there any other better ways ?

Comment: Q: I have a car which uses a motor, is it possible to rip out the motor and keep the car working?  A: You will have to build your own motor. Q: Is there no better way? A: No.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to remove ffmpeg without affecting the functionalities. The major work in your code like decoding and encoding is done through ffmpeg API's. You may look for other decoders to support your code if you do not want to use ffmpeg library.